# PyQt4: How do I place an object in front of another object?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

For better understanding, I brought you a edited picture.

[image: QProgressBar in front of QTreeView]

In general, is it possible to place a widget in front of another widget? 
For example, on the picture above, you can see a `QProgressBar` placed in front of `QTreeView`.

Imagine a situation in which all records are loaded into `QTreeView`. During this process, the user should be informed how far the loading process is. I know that you can also place the `QProgressBar` above or below the `QTreeView`. But I wondered if it's also possible to place the `QProgressBar` in front of `QTreeView`?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it is possible to place a widget in front of another widget.

1. First of all drag a widget(Suppose a QTreeView) in a main window.
2. Then right click on the QTreeView and then click on Layout Alignment.
3. Then choose the alignment left or right and after that drag the another widget(Suppose QProgressBar) in front of your first widget.

Comment: I am missing somting. I am using QDesigner with Qt4.8 and I did exactly as you described it, but it **doesn't work**. Well when I follow your discription the `QProgressBar()` Isn't in front of `QTreeView`, but either left or right.

Comment: @Sophus I have not written the answer, I have only edited it. :)

Comment: Oh I am sorry about that :)

Comment: @Sophus 
Although I doubt that answer works. I will try to propose a solution.